# Need suggestion in GIT workflow when direction of the project has changed

Tags: git

I was building something, it was a working prototype but had glitches and now we decided to use a library to do some heavy-lifting for us, and then code it on top of that. As of now I have been just committing to master. How should I proceed now?

- Should I create a branch of master and push new code in there and let master be in this state?
- Should I tag the last commit and then continue working on master?

What's your opinion on how should I handle the workflow when the direction of the project has changed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you'll want your code available until you implement the library create a new branch and start implementing it on the master when you are done with implementing your library create a tag and then merge your new branch.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the situation. I may not even revisit this code state. Are you saying that I should create a new branch right now  to which I can switch back if I need to work on it and continue my usual development in master only?

Comment: If you need a stable piece of code to work all the time create a branch and tag it before merging in either way even if you dont need a stable code then still the correct thing to do would be tagging it.

Comment: Yep, I tagged it and started work on another branch. If things work out in this direction, I will eventually merge it back to master. Thanks!